# Scheme and Lisp best practices: recursion yes for Scheme, no for Lisp?

Tags: scheme, common-lisp, racket, elisp

As I understand -- and I'm here to be corrected if wrong -- good Scheme practice is to do anything requiring looping, repeating with recursion, and, furthermore, overflow won't be a problem because tail-recursion is built-in. Lisp, however, doesn't have protection from overflow, hence, all the loop iterative macros (`loop`, `while`, etc). And so in real-world Lisp you usually don't use recursion, while Scheme wants it all but exclusively.

If my assumptions are true, is there a way to be "pure" with Lisp and not risk overflow? Or is this too much swimming against the stream to use recursion in Lisp? I recall from *The Little Schemer* how they give you a thorough workout with recursion. And there was an earlier edition called *The Little Lisper*. Did it give you the same recursion workout in Lisp? And then *Land of Lisp* left me confused about whether loops or recursion was "best practice."

What I'm trying to do is decide whether to use Racket inside of Emacs Org-mode or just use built-in Elisp for beginner students. I want students to stay as purely functional as possible, e.g., I don't want to explain the very new and difficult topic of recursion, then say "Oh, but we won't be using it..."

Comment: Scheme is a Lisp, just like C++ is an Algol. How about being more specific and compare Scheme with Common Lisp or ELisp.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> As I understand -- and I'm here to be corrected if wrong -- good Scheme practice is to do anything requiring looping, repeating with recursion, and, furthermore, overflow won't be a problem because tail-recursion is built-in.

This is correct as far as I know.

> Lisp, however, doesn't have protection from overflow [...]

Not exactly. Most self-respective Common Lisp implementations provide tail-call merging (with some restrictions, see https://0branch.com/notes/tco-cl.html). The difference is that there is no requirements from the language specification to have it. That grants compiler writers more freedom when implementing various Common Lisp features. Emacs Lisp does not have TCO, except in the form of libraries like [recur](https://github.com/VincentToups/recur) or [tco](https://github.com/Wilfred/tco.el) (self-recursion).

> ... hence, all the loop iterative macros (loop, while, etc). And so in real-world Lisp you usually don't use recursion, while Scheme wants it all but exclusively.

The difference is mostly cultural. Take a REPL (Read-Eval-Print-*Loop*). I think it makes more sense to consider the interaction as a loop rather than a infinitely tail-recursive function.  Somehow, there seem to be some reluctance in purely functional languages to even consider loops as a primitive control structure, whereas iterative processes are considered more elegant. Why not have both?

> If my assumptions are true, is there a way to be "pure" with Lisp and not risk overflow? Or is this too much swimming against the stream to use recursion in Lisp?

You can certainly use recursion in Lisp, provided you do not abuse it, which should not be the case with small programs. Consider for example that `map` in OCaml is not tail-recursive, but people still use it regularly. If you use SBCL, there is a section in the manual that explains how to enforce tail-call elimination.

> What I'm trying to do is decide whether to use Racket inside of Emacs Org-mode or just use built-in Elisp for beginner students. I want students to stay as purely functional as possible, e.g., I don't want to explain the very new and difficult topic of recursion, then say "Oh, but we won't be using it..."

If you want to teach functional programming, use a more functional language. In other words, between Racket and Emacs Lisp, I'd say Racket is more appropriate for students. There are more materials to teach functional programming with Racket, there is also Typed Racket.

Comment: 'provide tail-call merging' - but usually with restrictions. TCO creates a bunch of problems in CL and implementations may have also implementation limits. See for example: https://0branch.com/notes/tco-cl.html

Comment: Take a look at the formulation of structural recursion vs. generative recursion in HtDP (www.htdp.org). When recursion follows the structure of self-referential data, it's *vastly* easier for students to grasp. Also, I think Greg Hendershott's racket-mode is currently the favored emacs racket environment, assuming you're allergic to DrRacket.

Comment: Curious. What about geiser? I'm using geiser with org-mode.

Comment: I would have gone for DrRacket as IDE and used Advanced student with lambda. It allows the students to step through the code, something that is not possible with the other languages. I learned recursion with Java. I don't think TCO should be an issue in order to learn a language, but I do think all languages should aquire it. My first lisp was CL and it has its share of good parts.

Answer (score 6):

There are a lot of differences between the typical Lisp dialects and the various Scheme dialects:

**Scheme**

- requires tail call optimization
- favors tail recursion over imperative loop constructs
- dislikes imperative control flow
- provides functional abstractions
- tries to map control structures to functions (see for example CALL-WITH-CURRENT-CONTINUATION)
- implements some looping macros as extensions

**Lisp**

Parts of this applies for Lisp dialects like Emacs Lisp, Common Lisp or ISLisp.

- has low level control flow, for example GOTO like constructs: don't use them in user level code, sometimes they may be useful in macros.
- does not standardize or even provide tail call optimization: for maximum portability don't require TCO in your code
- provides simple macros: DO, DOTIMES, DOLIST: use them where directly applicable
- provides complex macros: LOOP, or ITERATE as a library
- provides functional abstractions like MAP, MAPCAR, REDUCE

Implementations typically have hard limits on stack sizes, which makes non-TCO recursive functions problematic. Typically one can set a large stack size upfront or extend the stack size at runtime.

Also tail call optimization has some incompatibilities with dynamic scope constructs like special variables or similar.

For TCO support in Common Lisp see: [Tail Call Optimisation in Common Lisp Implementations](http://0branch.com/notes/tco-cl.html)

**Style**

- Some prefer recursive functions, but I would not use it generally. Generally I (that's my personal opinion) prefer explicit loop constructs over general recursive calls. Others prefer the idea of a more mathematical approach of recursive functions.
- If there is a higher-order function like MAP, use that.
- If the loop code gets more complex, using a powerful LOOP statement can be useful

Answer (score 3):

In Racket [the looping construct of choice is `for`.](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/for.html)

Racket (like Scheme) also has [TCO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call), so in principle you can
write all looping constructs using function calls - it just isn't
very convenient.

Answer (score 1):

There is no Tail Call Optimisation (TCO) in Emacs Lisp, so even tho I personally like recursion very much, I'd generally recommend against its use in Elisp (except of course in those cases where it's the only natural choice).

Elisp as a programming environment is fairly good, but I must agree with "coredump" and would recommend Racket instead, which has great support for beginners.